# Insert a new line or an empty line between two sentences

Tags: python-3.x, insert, text-files, line

i have a text file as the output of another program. I want to insert a white space above the line that starts with 'Sentence #'

this is what i currently have:

```
Sentence #26024 (5 tokens):
Today is a good day
[Text=Today CharacterOffsetBegin=1607176 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607178 PartOfSpeech=IN Lemma=if]
[Text=is CharacterOffsetBegin=1607179 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607181 
PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=yo]
[Text=a CharacterOffsetBegin=1607182 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607186 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=girl]
[Text=good CharacterOffsetBegin=1607187 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607193 PartOfSpeech=JJ Lemma=doesnt]
[Text=day CharacterOffsetBegin=1607202 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607205 
root(ROOT-0, today-1)
root(today-1, is-2)
dobj(a-2, good-3)
amod(day-3, good-4)
Sentence #26025 (4 tokens):
if you can help 
[Text=if CharacterOffsetBegin=1607223 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607225 PartOfSpeech=IN Lemma=if]
[Text=you CharacterOffsetBegin=1607226 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607229 PartOfSpeech=PRP Lemma=you]
[Text=can CharacterOffsetBegin=1607230 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607233 PartOfSpeech=MD Lemma=can
mark(help-4, if-1)
nsubj(help-4, you-2)
aux(help-4, can-3)
```

This is what i want it to look like:

```
Sentence #26024 (5 tokens):
Today is a good day
[Text=Today CharacterOffsetBegin=1607176 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607178 PartOfSpeech=IN Lemma=if]
[Text=is CharacterOffsetBegin=1607179 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607181 
PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=yo]
[Text=a CharacterOffsetBegin=1607182 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607186 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=girl]
[Text=good CharacterOffsetBegin=1607187 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607193 PartOfSpeech=JJ Lemma=doesnt]
[Text=day CharacterOffsetBegin=1607202 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607205 
root(ROOT-0, today-1)
root(today-1, is-2)
dobj(a-2, good-3)
amod(day-3, good-4)

Sentence #26025 (4 tokens):
if you can help 
[Text=if CharacterOffsetBegin=1607223 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607225 PartOfSpeech=IN Lemma=if]
[Text=you CharacterOffsetBegin=1607226 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607229 PartOfSpeech=PRP Lemma=you]
[Text=can CharacterOffsetBegin=1607230 CharacterOffsetEnd=1607233 PartOfSpeech=MD Lemma=can
mark(help-4, if-1)
nsubj(help-4, you-2)
aux(help-4, can-3)
```

Can anyone please provide pointers. Thanks

I can't do it manually because it's a large file that will need thoussand of spaces inserted.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did, in case anyone else has a similar problem.

```
file = open("nameofoldfile.txt", 'r')
filelines = file.readlines()
for lines in filelines:
    lines = lines.strip()
    if lines.startswith('Sentence #'):
       print('\n')
       print(lines)
    else:
       print(lines)
```

then i saved the file to a new text file by running on the command prompt

```
python nameoffile.py > nameoftextfile.txt
```